# Need code for removing all unicode characters in vb6

Tags: unicode, vb6, unicode-string

I need code for removing all unicode characters in a vb6 string.

Comment: All characters are Unicode. Can you narrow it down a bit? Any specific characters you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is UTF-16 text (as normal VB6 String values all are) and you can ignore the issue of surrogate pairs, then this is fairly quick and reasonably concise:

```
Private Sub DeleteNonAscii(ByRef Text As String)
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim Char As String

    I = 1
    For J = 1 To Len(Text)
        Char = Mid$(Text, J, 1)
        If (AscW(Char) And &HFFFF&) <= &H7F& Then
            Mid$(Text, I, 1) = Char
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next
    Text = Left$(Text, I - 1)
End Sub
```

This has the workaround for the unfortunate choice VB6 had to make in returning a signed 16-bit integer from the `AscW()` function.  It should have been a Long for symmatry with `ChrW$()` but it is what it is.

It should beat the pants off any regular expression library in clarity, maintainability, and performance.  If better performance is required for truly massive amounts of text then SAFEARRAY or CopyMemory stunts could be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Function StripUnicodeCharactersFromString(ByVal inputValue As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(inputValue, "[^\u0000-\u007F]", String.Empty)
End Function
```

Vb6 - not sure will

```
sRTF = "\u" & CStr(AscW(char))
```

work? - You could do this for all char values above 127

Comment: That sounds a bit like VB.NET rather than VB6.

Comment: n VB6 all strings are unicode, can you therefore clarify, do you believe you are accidentally reading something that is UTF-8 as if it were Unicode or a OEM page code?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but it's possible that they're reading UTF-8 strings and want to remove all non-ASCII characters from it, yes. That's why I asked for clarification on the question.

Comment: It isn't actually true that all strings are Unicode (UTF-16LE) since it is quite possible to assign any arbitrary string of bytes to them.  Thus they can contain any ANSI codepage encoding, UTF-8, binary data, garbage, or anything.  However UTF-16LE/UCS2 is the normal "native" encoding you always have unless a program does something special.  I agree that the original question is vague and naive though, leaving much open to guessing about the actual problem to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

StrConv is the command for converting strings.

**StrConv Function**

Returns a Variant (String) converted as specified.

**Syntax**

```
StrConv(string, conversion, LCID)
```

The StrConv function syntax has these named arguments:

**Part Description**

```
string Required. String expression to be converted. 

conversion Required. Integer. The sum of values specifying the type of conversion to perform. `128` is Unicode to local code page (or whatever the optional LCID is) 

LCID Optional. The LocaleID, if different than the system LocaleID. (The system LocaleID is the default.)
```